# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING : please tell me how to fix it

Tags: java, android, json, api, gson

I am using this code :

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient().build())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
```

**Data from api :**

```
{"articles": [{"id": "47fdaba96844dc0a8b4580facb60f018a67f1b23"
```

**For clear view:**

```
{"articles": ***space*** [{"id": ***space*** "47fdaba96844dc0a8b4580facb60f018a67f1b23" in original
```

**And data expected:**

```
{"articles":[{"id":"47fdaba96844dc0a8b4580facb60f018a67f1b23"
```

**Error:**

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 5109 path

Comment: That error seems to be a lot further than the beginning of the json, which is all you posted. I'd suggest you paste the full response inside a text editor and go look at that column to see if there's something wrong with the returned json.

Comment: You are getting String in Response but you expecting an object. That's the problem.

Comment: @RithikBanerjee Yupp i konw that but how to resolve it

Comment: whats the json you are sending to api?

Comment: i have mentioned in the question...FOR CLEAR VIEW

Comment: have you found solution for this if yes please add solution below